# Why use a build tool with Selenium

Tags: maven, selenium, ant

I am using Selenium for automation with Eclipse and TestNG.
Whenever required I execute script from testng.xml.
Why do I need a Build tool loke Maven or Ant because Compiling and execution work taken care by Eclipse.
Only possible reason that I can think of are:
1. Scheduling using Windows 'Task Schedular'
2. Ant allows creating a batch file for execution, so execution gets simplified.
2. Craeting ReportNG reports that are triggered through ANT

Is there any other good reason?

Also why do I need Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

- *Jenkins* can be really helpful when you want **Continuous Integration
  builds** to be Tested frequently.
- In the environment where **continuous development and Continuous

  Integration** goes hand in hand we can use *Jenkins* to test the build
  regularly.
- With Selenium Automation we can build/develop the automation script
  for the developed builds. Once the Automation is developed we can
  create a bat file and use **Jenkins to run the bat file.**
- With *Jenkins* we can also **set the time duration** when to execute the
  test builds like every day at 12:00 pm IST. Also we can get easily
  notified if any test build execution fails because Jenkins also
  provide features to send email notification on failure.
- Also in some odd cases where we need to test the AUT on Linux/Unix
  environment we can easily deploy the Automation on the such Test
  system and use **ANT to run the Selenium Automation from command
  prompt.**